# How to use htaccess to restrict access to script when rewriting?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, http-authentication

I have a php script that relies on the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ script.php/go [QSA,L]
```

So when someone visits http://example.com/foo, the script is called script.php/foo. This should be publicly visible.

When I visit http://example.com/script.php/adminstuff/ I'd like to use http basic authentication. (I know how to use this in the basic case.) How will this react with the rewrite rules above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couold use `<Location>` tag:

```
<Location http://example.com/script.php/adminstuff/>
      AuthType xxxx
      ...
</Location>
```

Comment: Is there something analogous that can be used in an .htaccess file? If not I can use this recipe, but I'd prefer to have it in .htaccess. Thanks.